# ¿Cómo descomponer una cadena en varios trozos pero conservando una clave común?

Tags: r

Tengo un df con dos variables. Una con fecha y la otra es una cadena de longitud variable que contiene una referencia que está compuesta por los 3 primeros dígitos al principio de la cadena general y después de cada espacio en blanco que pueda haber. Y puede haber 0 o más espacios en blanco. Cada referencia, junto con la fecha, es la clave para otro dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(
  "fecha" = as.Date(c("2020-01-23","2020-01-23","2020-01-24","2020-01-25","2020-01-26")),
  "referencias" = c("13443523units2.00",
                    "1382344523units3.002 3242425units34.2 14534645units4",
                    "135634645634units3.1",
                    "215346235units4.22 389436units1",
                    "98723462units234 18762units4.5 5466234units0.05 32426units1 5672613units2"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

He podido hacer el tratamiento de la columna referencias generando una lista y posteriormente aplicando unlist:

```
lista_df <- strsplit(df$referencias, " ", fixed = TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(lista_df)){
  lista_df[[i]] <-
    c(
      substr(lista_df[[i]], start = 1, stop = 3),
      rep(NA, max(unlist(lapply(lista_df, length))) - length(lista_df[[i]])))
}

df2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lista_df))
```

y generando este resultado

> ```
>   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
> 1 134 NA  NA  NA  NA
> 2 138 324 145 NA  NA
> 3 135 NA  NA  NA  NA
> 4 215 389 NA  NA  NA
> 5 987 187 546 324 567
> ```

Pero no he sido capaz de incluir la fecha en el proceso.

El resultado que quiero obtener es este otro

> ```
> fecha      referencia
> 2020-01-23 134
> 2020-01-23 138
> 2020-01-23 324
> 2020-01-23 145
> 2020-01-24 135
> 2020-01-25 215
> 2020-01-25 389
> 2020-01-26 987
> 2020-01-25 187
> 2020-01-25 546
> 2020-01-25 324
> 2020-01-25 567
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Me resulta más fácil presentarte una solución usando `tidyverse`, aunque tal vez, inicialmente, sea más compleja de entender:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(ref = str_split(referencias, " ")) %>% 
  unnest(ref) %>% 
  mutate(ref = substring(ref, 1, 3)) %>% 
  select(-referencias)
```

Comentarios:

- el `%>%` o "pipe" es un operador clásico usado en R (no es R base es del paquete `magrittr`), sirve para encadenar funciones, cuando tienes que hacer algo así: `fun3(fun2(fun1(df)))` con el "pipe" puedes escribir todo así: `df %>% fun1() %>% fun2() %>% fun3()` es más fácil de escribir y notablemente más claro.
- Con `mutate(ref = str_split(referencias, " "))` dividimos la cadena `referencias` en una lista variable con cada una de las cadenas separadas por el espacio.
- Con `unnest(ref)` expandimos los datos hacia abajo, de tal forma que por cada cadena se genera una nueva fila.
- Con `mutate(ref = substring(ref, 1, 3))` recortamos los primeros 3 caracteres de cada cadena
- Con `select(-referencias)` simplemente quitamos la columna original.

Comment: No sé como se ponen los aplausos aquí pero dados están. Era exactamente lo que quería porque me permite "heredar" otros campos. Y las dos soluciones me vienen bien para aprender. Muchas gracias. Isaac

Answer (score 0):

Eventualmente, con R base, podrías hacer algo así:

```
refs <- strsplit(df$referencias, " ")           # Dividimos las cadenas
df$times <- sapply(refs, length)                # Contamos cuantas cadenas x fila
refs <- unlist(sapply(refs, substring, 1, 3))   # Nos quedamos con los 3 primeros chars.

df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, rep, df$times))  # Repetimos filas por cada cadena 
df$ref <- refs                                  # asignamos las cadenas
df <- df[,-c(2,3)]                              # quitamos columnas innecesarias
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y la velocidad. Me había encallado.